# How can I import data from one Ubuntu version (say 11.04 ) to 12.04.?

Tags: 12.04, migration

I want to import some bookmarks, browser history, and contents of my home directory. I have both 11.04 and 12.04 installed on my system.

Is there any way to import my data from older version?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I use both Firefox and Chrome

Comment: With Chrome, if you are logged in to your Google account, and synch everything, it will synch between installations.

Comment: What contents of your home directory do you plan to import?

Comment: The `Backup` section of this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/279625/11932) might be of help to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your files, just copy the folders that you want to save like Downloads, Documents, Music, etc. to a different partition, Re-install Ubuntu, and after the installation is done copy the folders over.

To copy browsing history, and other important info:

Firefox:
You can do that by copying the relevant data files from the profile folder on the old computer to the samet folder on the new computer. The location of the profile folder `~/.mozilla/firefox`

Chrome:

The Chrome bookmarks, history, and settings are in `~/.config/google-chrome/Default` .  Copy this folder, re-install chrome and put it back into the same location.

For bookmarks:

Firefox:

[image]

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

**Chrome sync** 
To sync your information in the browser like history, passwords, bookmarks, etc. Follow these easy steps:

1. Click the settings button inside Chrome (the tool)
2. Click on settings
3. Sign in at the top of the page with your Google account.
4. Select what info you want to be synced and you are off!

Follow the same steps in the other browser to sync it.

Comment: When using Chrome, it's easier to log in with a Google account and sync everything, just wanted to point out there's an easier way than to copy bookmarks(and everything else).

Comment: @Alvar Good point (Plus 1). I just don't use chrome that much.  Feel free to edit, and add that.

Comment: All done now :)